# Changing type of Source.Name

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

When I import a folder with PDF files, the files are ordered incorrectly. When sorting by ascending, the order is *1.pdf, 10.pdf, 11.pdf, 2.pdf,...* instead of *1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf...*

[image]

I assume this is because the `Source.Name` column is of the `Text` type, so the files are sorted lexicographically.

The issue is that I can't change the type of the column. If I try to select `Whole Number`, or any other type, then every file name becomes an error.

Is there a way to bypass or solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Highlight column, go to transform ribbon and select extract -> text before delimiter. Use a full stop . for the delimiter. Then you can change the type to whole number.